# Lambda Function get turned into BiConsumer

Tags: java, lambda

I am trying to work out how this works.
I am going to list what I believe is happening and hopefully someone can tell me I am wrong in places. Or tell me how/why this works.

```or-tag-here
public BiConsumer<List<T>, T> accumulator() {
    return List::add;
}
```

1. A method called accumulator that accepts nothing and returns a BiConsumer method.
2. `accumulator` returns a *reference* to the `add` method on the context of a `List` as the `BiConsumer`
3. The actual `add` method on a `List` is actually a `Function<T, Boolean>`, takes in `T` and returns a boolean

This is where I get into the guessing realm.

4. It is calling the `add` method, on the instance of the `List` that is the first argument of the `BiConsumer`.

I know internally it must be doing.

```or-tag-here
public BiConsumer<List<T>, T> accumulator() {
    return (list, item) -> list.add(i);
}
```

I understand that it can ignore the return type of the `add` method, so it can pretend `Function<A, B>` is `Consumer<A>`

But I just don't understand the **black magic** that turns a `BiConsumer` runs a `Consumer` or `Function` on the instance of the first argument of the `BiConsumer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not black magic. It is well specified [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

> The following is an example of a reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type:
>
> ```
> String[] stringArray = { "Barbara", "James", "Mary", "John",
>     "Patricia", "Robert", "Michael", "Linda" };
> Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
> ```
>
> The equivalent lambda expression for the method reference `String::compareToIgnoreCase` would have the formal parameter list `(String a, String b)`, where a and b are arbitrary names used to better describe this example. The method reference would invoke the method `a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)`.

When you have something like `SomeType::instanceMethod`, it can be converted to a function accepting two arguments, the first being the instance to call the method on. It just *can*, because the language spec says so.

Comment: So `Function` methods can be turned into `BiFunctions` as well as `BiConsumers`. Good to know.

Comment: @WORMSS if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it!

Comment: Well, your answer was `because the language spec says so.` .. Not the greatest.. Your answer tells me something I didn't know, but not exactly the best answer.. So I will wait, see if anyone can add to that.

Comment: @WORMSS so what do you want to know? How the compiler works? You want to see the source code of the compiler?